# How to call a method inde an Xlam from C++ Unmanaged XLL file

Tags: c++, excel, vba

I have an Xlam addin with some methods, I'd like to call these methods from a C++ Unmanaged Xll file, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the [Excel12v](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687851.aspx) function?